# Java Hex number increase by one

Tags: java, arrays, hex

I have some auto generated ids represented as a HEX String. I want to find the next 1000 values. For instance, let's suppose I have the following string

```
String keyFrom = "536a11dae4b062cab536549d";
```

How can I get from a java code the following, into String?

```
536a11dae4b062cab536549e 
536a11dae4b062cab536549f
536a11dae4b062cab53654a0 
536a11dae4b062cab53654a1
536a11dae4b062cab53654a2 ... etc.
```

Answer (score 3):

Use BigInteger as below

```
BigInteger decimal = new BigInteger("536a11dae4b062cab536549d",16);
        for ( int i=0;i<1000;i++){
            decimal = decimal.add(BigInteger.ONE);
            System.out.println(decimal.toString(16));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your `String` to [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) and increment it:

```
BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(hexString, 16);
for(int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; ++i) {
    // do something with bigInt...
    System.out.println(bigInt.toString(16));
    bigInt = bigInt.add(BigInteger.ONE);
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: The Q asks for the next 1000 values; you print the original value and the next 999.

Comment: Haha yes. Well he might have to do the correction himself :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: If your using hex strings longer than ~8 characters, use the solution using BigInteger above.

Use Integer#parseInt(String, 16) to parse the hex string into an integer, add one to it, and then use Integer#toHexString to turn it back to hexadecimal.

```
String hexString = "A953CF";
// 16 sepcifies the string to be in base 16, hexadecimal
int hexAsInt = Integer.parseInt(hexString, 16); 
hexAsInt += 6; // Add 6
String newHexString = Integer.toHexString(hexAsInt);
System.out.println(newHexString);

--> A953D4
```

- [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)
- [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString%28int%29)